# How do I set the name of a form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I tried

```
<%= form_tag ("/ombcauth", name:"ombc_form") do %>
```

But it gave me a syntax error:

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
>   ...append=  form_tag ("/ombcauth", name:"ombc_form") do @output...

I also tried

```
<%= form_tag ({action:"/ombcauth"}, {name:"ombc_form"}) do %>
```

But that also gave me a syntax error

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
>   ...form_tag ({action:"/ombcauth"}, {name:"ombc_form"}) do @outp...

I need to reference the form in a link to submit.

```
<%= link_to "OMBC Auth", "#", {onClick: "document.ombc_form.submit(); return false;"} %>
```

rails --version
Rails 3.2.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct. The problem is in the white space between `form_tag` and `(`:

```
<%= form_tag("/ombcauth", name:"ombc_form") do %>
```

Or without parenthesis:

```
<%= form_tag "/ombcauth", name:"ombc_form" do %>
```

Hope this helps!